# Ajuda com exibição de array de janelas (modelo WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

Seja o trecho de código:

```
Janela[] jnl = new Janela[3];



for(int i = 0; i < jnl.Length; i++)//inicializa os objetos janelas

{

       jnl[i] = new Janela();

}

//Código que produz o layout de que cada janela vem aqui.


for(int i = 0; i < jnl.Length; i++ )//Deveria chamar as janelas uma a uma, mas....

{

jnl[i].ShowDialog();// ....aqui, em vez de chamar apenas a janela indicada pelo 
                   //indice i, são chamadas todas as janelas do array em uma 
                   //única chamada. Na próxima interação, após eu fechar todas 
                   //as janelas abertas, é lançada a excepção descrita abaixo.

}
```

A mensagem do depurador é o seguinte:

`System.InvalidOperationException: 'Não será possível definir Visibility nem chamar Show, ShowDialog ou WindowInteropHelper.EnsureHandle depois que uma Janela for fechada.'`

Dá para notar que a exceção é devido eu estar tentado abrir uma janela que abriu e já foi fechada.

A questão é seguinte: porque é chamado o método `ShowDialog()` de todos os elementos do array de uma só vez, mas não apenas o elemento do índice `i` em cada interação com a declaração `jnl[i].ShowDialog();`?

Comment: A que excepção se refere? Sem conhecer o contexto em que isso acontece será difícil saber a razão..

Comment: Eu fui mais descritivo na pergunta.

Comment: Coloque todo o método.

Comment: Eu andei fuçando o problema e consegui especificar melhor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa aberração de bug mostrou-se ser parte de um dos processos do Visual Studio. A "depuração passo a passo" não mente: tudo se faz em apenas uma linha de execução (abertura de janelas sem serem explicitamente referenciadas). Penso que seja na parte das ferramentas de depuração (inserção de código auxiliar), pois o compilador está direitinho (criei um novo projeto e o código rodou!!!).